# How are treemaps hierarchical?

Tags: visualization

According to various sources on the internet, treemaps are a way to visualize **hierarchical**, tree-like data structures, for example the tree generated by hierarchical clustering.

I looked at a lot of treemaps and I just cannot seem to understand where/how the sense of hierarchy/nestedness is conveyed. It just seems to be tiles arranged next to each other. How do I know which tile is a parent/child of which other tile(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Treemaps are not very intuitive when trying to understand hierarchy levels. Sunburn chats are better.

- First hierarchy level is either shown by borders or different colors.
- Subsequent hierarchy level is represented by smaller rectangle which is part of bigger rectangle.

Refer this [article](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/treemaps/#:%7E:text=A%20hierarchical%20tree%20diagram,%20showing%20the%20structure%20of%20the%20S&P)